# javascript executor gives null when trying to access window.propertyname

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

I can see these many properties in console if I type `window` in Chrome console and hit enter.

But when I am trying to access same properties via `Javascript Executor` it gives me null.

**I tried:**

```
String homepage = jse().executeScript("window.origin", "found homepage").toString();
System.out.println("home page is  "+homepage);
```

and

```
String location = "function show_homepage() {var homepage = window.location.origin;return homepage;}"
String homepage = jse().executeScript(location, "found if email validated or not").toString();
System.out.println("Answer is "+homepage);
```

Reference:

1. [window object from selenium webdriver is empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55096220/window-object-from-selenium-webdriver-is-empty-array)
2. https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/javascriptexecutor-selenium-webdriver/
3. [View list of all JavaScript variables in Google Chrome Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934787/view-list-of-all-javascript-variables-in-google-chrome-console)

[image]

Comment: Java is to JavaScript as a Car is to a Carpet. don't tag Java for a JS question

Comment: Isn't that java code that I wrote. Viewers must know what language I am using for scripting. Also, I wanted java crowd to take a look at question, because Java developers uses `Javascript` pretty often. Isn't that the purpose of tagging, to send questions to particular community/crowd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The mistake I was doing, I was not returning function in JS snippet. I added one more line `return show_homepage();` and it worked.

```
String location = "function show_homepage() {"+
            "var homepage = window.location.origin;"+
            "return homepage;"+
            "}"+
            "return show_homepage();";
Object str = js().executeScript(location, "");
System.out.println(str.toString());
```